# how to check if a database is mysql or mariadb

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have some problems with a database. I think it might be mysql, my own database is probably mariadb. How can I check that?

Comment: Are we talking about a raw database file or a running database?

Comment: You want to check weather mariadb is installed or not?

Comment: @neferpitou  Yes. I'm not sure which of the two is installed in Lampp. I have a Akeeba backup that installs (thank god!) well on the live server, but acts weird when I install it on my localhost.

Comment: dpkg -l | grep mysql and for mariadb dpkg -l grep mariadb; if it shows nothing then it is not installed.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can do this on your login to the database from the terminal:

> mysql -u user -p

Enter your password and it displays the database name with the welcome message.[mysql welcome page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBHq8.png)[Maria Welcome page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3HTx.png)

Answer (score 8):

Since you mentioned  Lampp, this means you have Linux, Apache, MySQL, PHP and phpmyadmin. Use this command to see what is installed on your machine, Mysql or mariadb.

```
dpkg -l | grep -e mysql-server -e mariadb-server
```

Comment: *dpkg* command not found....

Comment: @RichardFu Which distro you are using? You might need to use this one instead: `rpm -qa | grep -e mysql -e mariadb`

Answer (score 6):

If you can perform a query :

```
SELECT VERSION();
```

I tested on a mariadb server and it shows :

```
5.5.60-MariaDB
```

Comment: For me: the result is "8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1"

Comment: Yes, on MySQL only the version number (8.0.23 here) is in there, and the database type is not shown.  So this isn't a great answer.

Answer (score 4):

If you can perform a query then i would suggest:

`SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";`

then look for `version_comment`
you should see something like
`MariaDB Server` OR `MySQL Community Server (GPL)`

Comment: For me: "version_comment" is "(Ubuntu)" ?

Comment: This does not result in "MySQL Community Server" on a mysql server.

Comment: Yes, It is Showing ```version_comment``` as `MariaDB Server` in SQL Query